# How do I solve this ratio problem?

Tags: problem-solving

Here is the problem:

If Bill takes 3 hours to paint a room and James takes 5 hours to paint a room, how long
will it take to paint a room if they work together? Show your working.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is a site relating to teaching mathematics, not solving math problems. If you add your own attempts you could try the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2):

This question should be migrated, and the answers will follow.

Consider Bills rate is 1/3 rooms per hour. James is 1/5 rooms per hour. Together, 8/15 rooms per hour. so 15/8 hours for one room.